# can't edit css in jekyll j1 theme

Tags: css, sass, jekyll

I'm running the jekyll j1 theme locally and attempting to edit the ccs. I've followed a few tutorials over the past week which instruct me to create a file at:

```
/assets/css/style.scss
```

and insert the following

```
---
---

@import "{{ site.theme }}";


  h2 {
   color: red;
 }



  h3 {
   color: blue;
 }
```

when I execute `bundle exec jekyll serve` or `yarn site`, the site fails to launch and delivers the error:

```
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.


  ╷
1 │ @import "j1-template";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
/starter/assets/css/style.scss 1:9  root stylesheet
  Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/style.scss':
                    Can't find stylesheet to import.
```

I can run css edits in a different jekyll build (with the minimal mistakes theme):

```
---
---

@charset "utf-8";

@import "minimal-mistakes/skins/{{ site.minimal_mistakes_skin | default: 'default' }}"; // skin
@import "minimal-mistakes"; // main partials



  h2 {
   color: red;
 }



  h3 {
   color: blue;
 }
```

but  I need to change the j1 theme and this doesn't use `@import "{{ site.theme }}";` . I'm hoping folks have some tips to help me get around this.

It looks to me like I need to be importing something else, but I'm not sure what it is . . .

Thanks for considering,

D

Answer (score 2):

in the end I got it working by making a new file in the root at `assets\css\adds.css`

no imports here, just a test snippet:

```
div#j1_footer.mt-4 div.copyright { 
    display:none;
  }
```

and under the front matter in the .md files that I need to reference the new css:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/adds.css">`

:)

Answer (score 0):

As [this answer suggests](https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes/issues/220#issuecomment-481644934), try to add `Encoding.default_external = Encoding.find('utf-8')` into `D:\applications\Ruby25-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.5.0\gems\sass-3.7.4\lib\sass\engine.rb`, like this:

```
......
51 require 'sass/importers'
52 require 'sass/shared'
53 require 'sass/media'
54 require 'sass/supports'
55
56 Encoding.default_external = Encoding.find('utf-8')
57
58 module Sass
......
```

Because apparently, [that's required to do in Windows](https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes/issues/220#issuecomment-627388306):

> If you're building on Windows then there's (probably) a hidden UTF-8
> BOM at the beginning of the file which you'll need to find a way to
> get rid of. This is a blind guess (you haven't yet provided the error
> trace) but my experiences point in this way.

If it still doesn't work, try to remove the `---` from the beginning of your SCSS file and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for this :)                                                                                                                   I'm on OSX, it looks like the file is at   `/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sass-embedded-1.57.1-x86_64-darwin/lib/sass`   for me.                                                           I added the line `Encoding.default_external = Encoding.find('utf-8')` but no change. I still get the same error as above.  I removed the `---` at the top of my `styles.scss` file which lets me launch jekyll without an error, but my style changes have no effect.